# Code for functionality like "valid pointer or default" and "true or default"

Tags: c++

Relatively new to C++, not sure if I'm doing everything right, any advice would be appreciated. The site does not allow me to post this question with that little actual text, so I am artificially extending it with this dummy text. Here's what I wrote:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class DefaultPointer {
    const T* value_pointer;
    const T default_value;

public:
    DefaultPointer(const T* ptr, const T& def) : value_pointer(ptr), default_value(def) {

    }

    const T get() {
        if (value_pointer == nullptr) {
            return default_value;
        }
        return *value_pointer;
    }
};

template<typename T>
class Default {
    const T value;
    const T default_value;

public:
    Default(const T& value, const T& def) : value(value), default_value(def) {

    }

    const T get() {
        if (!(bool)value) {
            return default_value;
        }
        return value;
    }
};

int main() {
    const int test_value = 1;
    const int* const pointer = &test_value;
    std::cout << DefaultPointer<int>(pointer, 0).get();
}
```

Comment: `get()` is not very idiomatic [tag:c++]. Prefer `operator *()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some considerations:

1. **Use of `const`**:

   - In your `DefaultPointer` and `Default` classes, the `get` method does not modify any member variables, so it's good practice to mark it as `const` to indicate that calling this method won't change the object's state.
   - For the member variables `value_pointer` and `value`, consider if you really want them to be `const`. This makes your objects immutable after they're constructed, which might be your intention. If you ever need to change the pointer or value after construction, you'll need to remove the `const`.
2. **Checking for null pointers and zero values**:

   - In `Default`, you check `if (!(bool)value)`. This works for numeric types where `0` is implicitly convertible to `false`, but it might not be clear or applicable for all types T. Consider if there's a more explicit or type-safe way to handle this, depending on what types you expect `T` to be.
3. **Return Type Optimization**:

   - Returning by `const T` is unusual. Typically, you'd return by value (`T`) or by `const T&` if you're returning a reference to an existing object (to avoid copying). Returning by `const T` prevents the caller from modifying the returned value, which is unnecessary for built-in types and might inhibit move semantics for user-defined types.
4. **Error Handling**:

   - Consider what should happen if an invalid pointer is passed to `DefaultPointer`. Your current implementation gracefully handles `nullptr`, but what about dangling or uninitialized pointers? This might be beyond the scope of your current practice but is worth thinking about as you advance.
5. **Usage Example**:

   - Your `main` function demonstrates usage of `DefaultPointer` but not `Default`. It might be beneficial to include an example of how `Default` is intended to be used, especially considering its reliance on the boolean conversion of `T`.
6. **Other practices to keep in mind**:

   - If you're using C++11 or newer, you can use `nullptr` instead of `NULL` for null pointer constants. It's more type-safe and clear.
   - Consider using smart pointers (`std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr`) if you plan to work with dynamically allocated memory. They help manage memory more safely and automatically.

Comment: I do actually expect the parameter of Default to have a `bool` operator. I now have a question: how do I check for a dangling or an uninitialized pointer? And is there a way that is considered a good practice for such a check?

Comment: There isn't a fullproof method to checking or I don't think there is